# Breaking/Pausing the Login Process the change an expired password

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I'm having a spot of bother here.
I'm working on a multi-tiered CAB application that uses a Web-service for authentication and a WinForms front-end.

Now, I've been asked to implement password expiry and have gotten the necessary details and I've used them to see if the user's password has expired, only thing is, I'm having trouble pausing the login process and "redirecting" to the ChangePassword form.

What I've been trying is throwing a custom exception called PasswordExpiredException(inherits System.Exception and later ApplicationExcetion when that didn't work) and calling ChangePassword.ShowDialog() in the catch. This is causing a headache because it's doing what I'm damned well telling it to do, and throwing an unseemly exception at log-on, if the password has expired.

So, can I un-throw my exception when it's done it's job?
OR, should I scrap the idea and do it "properly"? Not having any clue what that might be

**A basic run-through of the callstack at log on** ~~>

```
Logon.Cs.btnOK_Click ~~> wsAuthentication.GetProvider(GetUserDBInstace(UserName))~~>
ASPNETAuthentication.Authenticate(username,password)~~>
CheckIfExipred(MembershipUser.LastPasswordChangedDate) 
~Y~> throw PasswordExpiredException; //getting it to go back all the way to the UI, opening up ChangePassword.cs, leaving me with an authenticated user who's about to change his old password
~N~> //continue login, ignoring all my hard work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of throwing an exception, I would consider returning some sort of `AuthenticationResult`. It seems to me that you're trying to use exception handling to manipulate control flow. Exceptions should be exceptional. What you're suggesting sounds like a completely legitimate business rule.

```
public class AuthenticationResult {
  public bool AreCredentialsValid { get; set; }
  public bool IsAccountLocked { get; set; }
  public bool RequiresPasswordChange { get; set; }
}
```

You can then query the returned object to determine what to do next, instead of trying to handle an exception.

Answer (score 0):

An expired password is not an exceptional condition at login (it may be at other times, such as when checking authorization for a particular action), so throwing your `PasswordExpiredException` from your login method is probably not the best way to control your flow in this case.

Perhaps your login method could return a user object that contains a boolean specifying that the password is expired, or you could use an `out` parameter on the login to return the same info.  I would prefer the former, as I like to avoid `out` parameters if at all possible.